# Tests fail when run as part of build from TFS but run successfully locally

Tags: c#, selenium, tfs

I have selenium tests in C#. I am using Selenium RC to run scripts on a server box. All my scripts run fine when I run from local machine but I get following exception when I try running the scripts as part of build from TFS.

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: Can you please share code; exception details etc... .

Comment: This is a coding error and we've got no idea what your code looks like........